# Get SerializedName Retrofit of this json

Tags: android, class, retrofit2, pojo

I'm using Retrofit for send Rest Request ; I'm using Pojo Class and SerializedName Parameters for getting Response, but can't create a class for this JSON Data.

> who to get data array in all content items with SerializedName Retrofit2

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "slider",
      "title": "",
      "analyticsAction": {},
      "data": [
        {
          "image": {},
          "title": {},
          "subTitle": {},
          "url": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "vendorList",
      "title": "",
      "analyticsAction": {},
      "data": [
        700,
        266,
        15
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "productList",
      "title": "",
      "analyticsAction": {},
      "data": [
        34600,
        34266,
        3456
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "banner",
      "title": "",
      "analyticsAction": {},
      "data": {
        "image": {},
        "title": {},
        "url": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check here http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: _"But can't create a class for this JSON Data_" Why not?

Comment: json is broken. you can not create a logical class with this respons.